# Pass(add) a parameter to a function if something is true in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class `BaseSettings` which has a `set` function.
I am checking if the settings in the class are **only** set from the class, not from environment variables. 
I am doing this in a subclass of `BaseSettings` which is named `settings`.

I want to add a hidden parameter, i.e it cannot be set by the user, which tells that the setting is set from somewhere else. It can be a bool or something.

What I'm doing

What I actually want to know is how to "add" the parameter when checking the condition, I am going to use a private variable, using the `__` prefix

```
            if isinstance(Settings,BaseSettings):
            # Check if the settings are set from env var
                if super().set() in os.environ:
                   # Set the hidden parameter
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be set by the user"? Do you mean a user of your program, running it through CLI, web or similar? Or a user of your code, using the class in their own code and having access to your module? Is the code you have shown part of your class? What specific problem do you have setting a ``__`` name? You can just do that in a class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your issue is working with "hidden" data.  I coded up this example using a base class with "public", "private" (one underscore), and "hidden" (two underscores) members, and a subclass, along with some test data to illustrate:

```
class Secret():

    def __init__(self):
        self.not_secret=98
        self._secret=99
        self.__top_secret=100

class SubSecret(Secret):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def get_secrets(self):
        print(self.not_secret)
        print(self._secret)
        print(self._Secret__top_secret)

    def set_top_secret(self,the_data):
        self._Secret__top_secret = the_data

my_sub = SubSecret()
my_sub.set_top_secret(276543)
my_sub.get_secrets()
```

The output is:

```
98
99
276543
```

Note the trick to access the "hidden" top secret data.